# Блокировка скроллинга

Tags: javascript, css, webview

Раньше блокировал так:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = "hidden"
```

С обновлением webview (где то в феврале 2017) это перестало работать

Есть ли альтернатива? Кроме pozition:fixed

Answer (score 0):

Почему не работает?

```js
document.querySelector('#blockScroll').addEventListener('click', _ => document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden');
```

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
}

#blockScroll{
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px; top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='blockScroll' value='Блокировать скролл' />
Lorem<br />
ipsum<br />
dolor<br />
sit<br />
amet,<br />
consectetur<br />
adipisicing<br />
elit.<br />
Placeat<br />
molestias<br />
dolore<br />
harum<br />
quae<br />
aut<br />
nisi<br />
delectus<br />
necessitatibus<br />
quo,<br />
consequuntur<br />
beatae<br />
voluptatum<br />
illum<br />
iure<br />
iste,<br />
culpa<br />
tempora<br />
aliquam<br />
distinctio<br />
labore<br />
porro?<br />
Libero<br />
veniam<br />
distinctio<br />
autem<br />
suscipit<br />
maxime<br />
nulla<br />
porro,<br />
eum<br />
quasi<br />
iusto<br />
asperiores<br />
praesentium<br />
cumque<br />
amet<br />
aliquam<br />
sint<br />
quam<br />
consectetur<br />
facere!
```

Comment: это в хроме работает - в webview - нет